# Exception handling in Java: catch and throw again

Tags: java, exception

I'm following a Java programming course and we just learned Exception Handling in Java. I saw this code in the last homework correction:

```
public int getWinner() throws IllegalArgumentException {
  int winner;

  try {
    winner = GameRules.getWinner(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    throw e;
  }

  return winner;
}
```

My question would be: Why do we first catch the Exception e and throw it again?
I think if you do so, then the program will still be stoped so it's like not handling the exception. Maybe I am wrong, please point it out, thanks!

Comment: Is that the complete code? Is there any logging done in between? Is a different exception thrown? As written, the code makes little sense. Where did you see that?

Comment: Yeah, that's the complete code.

Comment: I saw this from homework correction. I should probably ask the TAs

Comment: I typically wrap and rethrow exceptions when it's in a situation where the exception arose as a fault of something preventable. Similarly, I may want to let others know about an exception raised in my service / classes, so I would wrap it and send it up for calling functions to interpret. Overall though, this will chain it, and you need to make a new exception there: `throw new RuntimeException("D'oh!", e);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you catch an exception as you want to perform some logging/record some metrics as part of the process. Re-throwing the exception means you can then pass the exception higher up the call-stack so it can be dealt with by a (centralised) error handler.

Not all exceptions are unrecoverable just because they occur, so throwing an exception doesn't necessarily cause the application to stop unless its allowed to bubble all the way up the call stack.

Catching the exception simply gives you the opportunity to decide what to do next when the exception occurs. Catching an exception and then ignoring it is typically bad practice.

Comment: Except according to the OP, nothing of the sort is done here, its literally the whole code.

Comment: yeah but it's just sample code - the expectation is probably to show you can catch and throw just as Rob explains

Comment: I get your point. Asking "why" we do it in this specific example... there's no reason to catch it explicitly and rethrow it. BUT if the question was a more generic "why would we ever do this"... I think I've answered that above... its possible and does occur in the realworld. Sometimes we wrap one exception in a more meaningful business logic exception. The original error contains the details of what really happened.

Comment: otherwise you'd just have the method as `return GameRules.getWinner(firstPlayer, secondPlayer);` and the signature would throw whatever exception getWinner() throws (if/when it occurs)